# script command writing content in windows format

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I ran this command

```
$ script -a 05112013.log
$ ls
$ Ctrl+D
```

I see the following content inside 05112013.log file,

```
Script started on Tue 05 Nov 2013 06:12:46 PM IST
^[]0;mmopuru@mmopuru:/zyme_shared/zyme_apps/zymenet/dev^G^[[?1034h[mmopuru@mmopuru dev]$ ls^M
^[[0m^[[00;33m05112013.log^[[0m   ^[[01;34mberkeleydb^[[0m  ^[[00;33mC:\nppdf32Log\debuglog.txt^[[0m  ^[[01;34mhttpd^[[0m         ^[[01;34mlib^[[0m           ^[[01;34mmemcached^[[0m  ^[[01;34mpython^[[0m      test.py      ^[[01;34mzyme_repo^[[0m^M
^[[01;34mapache-tomcat^[[0m  ^[[01;34mbin^[[0m         ^[[01;34mEGG-INFO^[[0m                    ^[[01;34mjobscheduler^[[0m  ^[[01;34mlibmemcached^[[0m  ^[[01;34mopenldap^[[0m   ^[[01;34mrepository^[[0m  ^[[01;34mzymenetwsgi^[[0m^M
^[]0;mmopuru@mmopuru:/zyme_shared/zyme_apps/zymenet/dev^G[mmopuru@mmopuru dev]$ exit^M

Script done on Tue 05 Nov 2013 06:12:51 PM IST
```

why **script** command logging content in windows format? means using ^M, ^G^[, ^[ etc characters for newline, tag etc?

Note: when I check file format using `:set ff?` in **vi** says `fileformat=unix`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not logging in Windows format, it is logging in raw (or non-canonical) format.  The way that `script` works is that it inserts itself as a terminal driver at the low-level (simplified).

The conversions that you usually see are done by the "line discipline".  Non-canonical terminal use is used by programs like `vi`.

See `man tcgetattr` for more detail than you really want.

To remove non-printable characters from `typescript` you can try this, *provided* you have a `sed` that supports POSIX character classes (e.g. modern Linux):

```
sed -r 's/[^[:print:]]//' typescript > final.file
```